# Android layout - How to make the controls appear to the left/right without padding?

Tags: android, layout, padding

I have defined 3 controls on my screen, placed in the following order: 
    button 
    - textView
    - button

I want to place the first button on the left side and place the textView in the middle. The second button should be on the right side.

However, I cannot find a way to force the buttons to stick to the left/right side and for the textView too stick to the middle.

This is the code:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="&lt;&lt;"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/TodayDataTextView"
    android:text="Today Data"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#0000ff"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=">>"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the screenshot:

[image]

And this is what I want to have (without the padding):

[image]

Comment: Add this in the xml file in the second button part -->
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

Comment: use weightSum and layout_weight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<RelativeLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="&lt;&lt;"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/TodayDataTextView"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Today Data"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#0000ff"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=">>"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

set layoutgravity and gravity as left, center and right respectively for all the three widgets

Answer (score 2):

You can try a RelativeLayout. Like this:

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="&lt;&lt;"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/TodayDataTextView"
            android:text="Today Data"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#0000ff"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=">>"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/button" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Please use a Relative Layout instead of a LinearLayout.
2. Add to Button

   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
3. Add to TextView

   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
4. Add to the Right Button

   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

   android:layout_centerVertical="true"

Comment: I was about to recommend this, too, but the TextView ends up floating to the top of the screen (and isn't centered vertically relative to the buttons).  You could try to fix this with margin, but that's messy.  A linear layout makes it easy to keep all three aligned.

Answer (score 2):

You could use layout weights to get exactly what you are looking for:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="&lt;&lt;"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Today Data"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="&lt;&lt;"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        />
```

[image: linear layout with weight]

Remember that Android makes two passes when determining the size and position of the components in a layout.  The first pass uses the `layout_width` and `layout_height` settings.  In this case it is `wrap_content` for most of the widgets which will make them their "natural" size to fit their content. The second pass uses the `layout_weight` attribute to allocate any remaining pixels.  Given that this is a horizontal linear layout, those pixels will be allocate to the horizontal size of the widgets.  Only the `TextView` specifies a weight attribute, so it will get 100% of the remaining pixels.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:gravity="left">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="<<" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.60"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="data"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:gravity="right">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="<<" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also working

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="&lt;&lt;"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TodayDataTextView"
        android:text="Today Data"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:text=">>"
            android:id="@+id/button" />

</LinearLayout>
```